# Show/Hide ContextMenuStrip outside the form

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I'm creating a simple clipboard manager application. It monitors the content of a clipboard. When a change occurs (throu the win api message loop) it fires up a method to capture current content of clipboard and creates new object called clipboarditem. Next its building a ContextMeuStrip which consits of several clipboarditems created previously. The items menu is accessed by a hotkey. It shows up this menu on certain position of the screen itemsMenu.Show(caretPosition);, with .Focus(), I want it to make it disappear after it loses the focus (eg. clicking somehwere else on the screen or switch applications by alt-tab). Found an event OnLoseFocus but I dont think its working properly because the menu wont even show up.

How to make ContextMenuStrip disappear after loosing focus and how to prevent from showing ContextMenuStrip in taskabr ?

Sorry for my language skills :)

Answer (score 0):

From a very quick look at the events that ContextMenuStrip contains, have you tried the "MouseCaptureChanged" event? It *may* help you with the losing focus issue.

For the showing in the taskbar issue, have you set "ShowInTaskbar" to false on the form you have your ContextMenuStrip (if you have it on a form)?